# MySQL query not outputting result only heading

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, ajax

I am currently practicing PHP and AJAX and I am trying to create an application that allows a user to search a database for product stock in real time. When the user types in a letter within one of the entries the headings show up but not the data. I'm not sure if I am doing it wrong but I'll let you guys be the judge of that. Code below:

> Results.php - Below

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Results</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "databaseName");
//edited out for safety 

if (!$con) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"jakeholc_ajaxtest");

$sql="SELECT * FROM stock WHERE name LIKE '%{$q}%'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Product name</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Quantity</th>
</tr>";

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['descr'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['price'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['quantity'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
}


echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Why are you using `mysqli_select_db()` if you're already providing a database name in `mysqli_connect()`?

Comment: Given the fact that you have no apparent errors, I think it's safe to assume that your query returns no results. You could do some very basic debugging to a) confirm this is the case, and b) figure out why you get no results

Answer (score 2):

`$q = intval($_GET['q']);` attempts to turn your input into an integer. Remove this line.

Comment: also, you will want to sanitize the input so you aren't hit with an SQL injection attack

Comment: Cheers for the input mate, it hasn't fixed the problem but i appreciate your efforts!

Comment: Also cheers for the heads up about the SQL injection prevention, I am aware of this but just wanted to get the basic functionality working before complicating it further :D

Comment: better yet replace `$q = intval($_GET['q']);` with `$q = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9\s-]/i', '', $_GET['q']);`

Comment: @BobK *"I am aware of this but just wanted to get the basic functionality working before complicating it further"* <- where does this attitude keep coming from? It's truly terrible

Comment: Sorry if i sounded ungrateful @Phil but as i mentioned in the description i am still trying to learn php and ajax so i think adding it in would just confuse me more, i wasn't trying to be rude

Comment: after removing the intval() line, what are you putting in q variable? I presume you are using the `URL?q=name` since you are using $_GET.

Comment: @BobK so learn it right the first time. Fixing security issues like this **after** the fact is much more difficult

Comment: Thanks @NerdsofTechnology that fixed it! Appreciate the input guys

Comment: replace `$sql="SELECT * FROM stock WHERE name LIKE '%{$q}%'";`
with `$sql='SELECT * FROM stock WHERE name LIKE "%' . $q . '%"';`

Comment: as a test can you add this debug line below `$sql='SELECT * FROM stock WHERE name LIKE "%' . $q . '%"';` ? :

`$sql='SELECT * FROM stock';` SEE if there are ANY results

Comment: @NerdsofTechnology why? Those strings a functionally the same. Also, MySQL string values should be single-quoted (by convention)

Answer (score 0):

you may try my code. I already tested this one. And everytime you entered a text, entered text will match some record from your database then if there's a record matched, then it will display the record matched on your entered text. Hope this helps :) Please note that the below code are the content of "ajax_search.php".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#search").keyup(function() {
var name = $('#search').val();
if (name == "") {
$("#display").html("");
}
else {
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "ajax_search.php",
data: {
search: name
},
success: function(html) {
$("#display").html(html).show();
}
});
} 
}); 
});
</script>   
</head>

<body>
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search Product Here..." />
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","databasename"); 
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Database Connection Failed: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
?>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
$key = $_POST['search'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM stock  WHERE name LIKE '%$key%' OR descr LIKE '%$key%' OR price LIKE '%$key%' OR quantity LIKE '%$key%' ";
$execute_query = mysqli_query($con, $query);
echo "<table border='3px' cellpadding='3px' cellspacing='3px' bgcolor='skyblue' align='center'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>Product Name</td>";
echo "<td>Description</td>";
echo "<td>Price</td>";
echo "<td>Quantity</td>";
echo "</tr>";
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($execute_query)) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$result['name']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$result['descr']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$result['price']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$result['quantity']."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
</table>
<div id="display">
<!-- Ouput will display here -->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```